# TYPO3 Extbase order by child records COUNT

Tags: count, sql-order-by, typo3, children, extbase

I have this model:

```
News -> 1:n -> Visit
News -> m:n -> FrontendUserGroup
FrontendUser -> 1:n -> Visit
```

So Visit shows which FrontendUser accessed which News.

I need to get all news for the currently logged in FrontendUser.
All News should be ordered DESC by the "datetime" property, but first should appear the news which are not visited yet by the logged in user.

This is the SQL which gives me the correct results:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tx_xxnews_domain_model_visit v WHERE v.news = n.uid AND v.fe_user = fu.uid) AS visits, 
    n.*

FROM tx_xxnews_domain_model_news AS n
    JOIN tx_xxnews_news_frontendusergroup_mm nfg ON n.uid = nfg.uid_local
    JOIN fe_users fu ON FIND_IN_SET(nfg.uid_foreign, fu.usergroup)

WHERE fu.uid = 2271 # logged in user id

ORDER BY visits ASC, n.datetime DESC
```

Is there any way to get this result with Extbase?

I tried in NewsRepository this:

```
protected $defaultOrderings = array(
    'COUNT(visits)' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
    'datetime' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING
);
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in fact not possible since $defaultOrderings expects properties, not SQL field names or functions.

As far as I know, the only possibility is to use`$query->statement('[YOUR QUERY]');`.

Comment: In this case, I guess I shouldn't hope too much for a way to handle enableFields automatically, right? :)

Comment: A little bit hacky, but you can use the enableFields method from the ContentObject if you don't want to write these conditions yourself.